# iOS Develop - Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'UITableViewController'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am learning to develop for iOS and I don't know so much about it. I am following this [tutorial](http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/).

On the ViewController I have this code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var feedItems: NSArray = NSArray()                      //Array de localizaciones
    var SelectedLocation: LocationModel = LocationModel()   //Referencia al modelo
    @IBOutlet weak var listTableView: UITableView!          //LIstView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //Inicializamos HomeModel

        //Delegamos a la vista los métodos de la tabla para rellenarla
        self.listTableView.delegate = self
        //Establecemos que la vista será el dataSource de la tabla
        self.listTableView.dataSource = self

        //Instanciamos el HomeModel, su dataSource y delegate para el tableView
        let homeModel = HomeModel()
        homeModel.delegate = self
        homeModel.downloadItems()
    }

    //implementamos el método del protocolo de HomeModel, en el guardamos los items que recibe a través
    //de delegation y llamamos a reloadData del tableView que hará que se active el método delegado
    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray) {

        feedItems = items
        self.listTableView.reloadData()
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of feed items
        return feedItems.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Retrieve cell
        let cellIdentifier: String = "BasicCell"
        let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier)!
        // Get the location to be shown
        let item: LocationModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! LocationModel
        // Get references to labels of cell
        myCell.textLabel!.text = item.address

        return myCell
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

When I try to compile I get the error:
`Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'UITableViewController` just inside viewDidLoad function. I know what the error means, the system can't convert implicit types. But, how can I fix the error? Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: change it to: `class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate`

Answer (score 4):

in your class you were implemnt the delegate and datasource method of Tableview . But you are not added the delegate Name in your class.

> Declare that your class conforms to the `UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate` protocol and implement any of those protocol methods that you need.

change this

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController
{
```

into

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
```

Comment: You are right. Thats my fault, I forgot that, didn't see. In other languages the class declaration means something completely different. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ProgramadorAdagal -- in previous is not occur but ios 9 onwards it is manodary.. any way have a happy day my bro..

Comment: It is changed, now I got the error `Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'HomeModelProtocol'` this is crazy and insane. Is there some tutorial for knowing the meaning, I mean, the theory of swift?

Answer (score 1):

In your ViewController.m where class definition is just started add
**UITableViewDelegate** and **UITableViewDataSource** by comma separated like this:

```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

      // your code will be here

   }
```